# Bootstrap carousel cannot process .each jquery from componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

i have issue why functionalities of repeat be not work how solved this? console.log in componentdidmount not appears

```
  renderCarouselItem() {
    console.log('(3) testing carousel di sebelum render');
    return _.map(this.props.editor_pick_data, function (value, key){
      return (
        pug`
        .carousel-item(className=${key == 0 ? 'active' : ''}, key=${key}, style=${{display: 'relative'}} )
          .col-md-3.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
            a.thumbnail(href="#")
              img.img-responsive(src=${value.item.images[1].big_thumbnail})
        `
      )
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      pug `
        div(style=${{background: 'red', height: 'auto'}})
          .col-lg-12.col-lg-centered.col-md-10.col-sm-8.col-sm-centered.col-md-centered.columns(style=${{height: 'auto'}})
            h2.divider Editor's Picks
            .col-md-12
              #carousel.carousel.slide(data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="1000")
                .carousel-inner
                  ${this.renderCarouselItem()}
                a.carousel-control-prev(href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev")
                  span.carousel-control-prev-icon(aria-hidden="true")
                  span.sr-only Previous
                a.carousel-control-next(href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next")
                  span.carousel-control-next-icon(aria-hidden="true")
                  span.sr-only Next
      `
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('teslah termount')
    this.props.fetchEditorPick();

    $('#carousel[data-type="multi"] .carousel-item').each(function (){
      console.log('(1) testing carousel in didmount')
    })
  }
```

but when in render i build carousel item not from function for rendercarouselitem the process work console.log() in ComponentDidMount will console.log 2x

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what pug is but your render is not returning anything.

Comment: oh sory my mistake forget to type return in render.
pug is just for simple to write code for development